# Vuetify: v-ripple can only be used on block-level elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I just started getting this error today, and it broke my whole site (because like a fool I'm loading Vuetify on page load).

Does anyone know what this means or how to fix it? Googling around didn't reveal anything helpful.

*Edit:*

To anyone who finds this because their site is also broken, it may be because of where you were loading `vuetify.min.css` from. For me I was getting at page load like so:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And solved the problem by importing it from the installed package instead with

```js
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

in `app.js`.

I'm still interested in learning about this `v-ripple` business, though.

Answer (score 7):

I got into the same problem and I solved by installing

> material-design-icons-iconfont

Run the following command to install:

```
npm install material-design-icons-iconfont
```

or, if you are running from yarn then:

```
yarn add material-design-icons-iconfont
```

Now import in main.js file:

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
```

You can read the vuetify documentation for more information:
[Vuetify Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue today and started going down the route of importing it as  suggested above when I noticed the header:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*!
* Vuetify v2.0.0-alpha.14
* Forged by John Leider
* Released under the MIT License.
```

It looks like they bumped the dist version (I'm working with 1.5.12). I updated my link href to:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.12/dist/vuetify.min.css
```

...and my site was put back together again. It's probably better practice to bring it in as a module but that'll be something for the backlog. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was I had both tslint and eslint installed. After I disabled eslint, it worked.