# Getting error: "[Vuetify] v-ripple can only be used on block-level elements" when deploying to Heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, vuetify.js, ruby-on-rails-6

I have been developing an app locally with Rails 6 sprinkled with Vue and Vuetify front end.  It all works fine locally. However, when I try to deploy it from Heroku I get the following error in the debug console

`[Vuetify] v-ripple can only be used on block-level elements`

The site loads but but looses all the formatting so just looks like plain text.  I have found this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798515/vuetify-v-ripple-can-only-be-used-on-block-level-elements) but none of these solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution for me.  I still had `stylesheet_link_tag` instead of `stylesheet_pack_tag` in the layouts/application.html.erb.  I changed from 'link' to 'pack' and it worked.  The answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328026/css-and-bootstrap-not-loading-in-rails-6-app-when-deployed-to-heroku) helped me find the answer